# Limitar registros de un campo en base a su Id SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Básicamente tengo una atributo multivariado, pero este solo puede tener 3 registros por Id como máximo

¿De qué forma podría limitar la cantidad de datos por Id en *SQL Server*?

Ejemplo: Una tabla con `#Carnet` y Correo electrónico, y que por cada carnet agregado este pueda tener un límite de 3 correos para agregar.

```
CREATE TABLE Persona(
    Idcarnet varchar(8)NOT NULL,
    Correo varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE Persona ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Persona PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: Puedes crear un trigger que evalúe cuantos registros tiene ese id y proceder a insertar el nuevo registro o no.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Que significa limitar? ¿impedir el alta de filas hasta cierta cantidad?¿hacer una consulta que solo retorne X filas por id? ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo y un poco más de detalle a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

No existe nada que sea totalmente confiable. Sin embargo, lo más sencillo con tan pocos valores es utilizar dos constraints: uno de llave primaria y otro de check.

Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
--Creamos una tabla para probar
CREATE TABLE PruebaLimite(
    ID tinyint NOT NULL,
    valor varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
--Agregamos la llave primaria
ALTER TABLE PruebaLimite ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PruebaLimite PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--Validamos que solo pueda tener 3 valores
ALTER TABLE PruebaLimite ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PruebaLimite CHECK (ID IN(1,2,3));

GO
--Tratamos de insertar 4 filas, una fallará.
INSERT INTO PruebaLimite VALUES(1, 'Valor 1');
INSERT INTO PruebaLimite VALUES(2, 'Valor 2');
INSERT INTO PruebaLimite VALUES(3, 'Valor 3');
INSERT INTO PruebaLimite VALUES(4, 'Valor 4');
GO
--Validamos las filas en la tabla
SELECT * FROM PruebaLimite
GO
--Limpiamos nuestra base de datos 
DROP TABLE PruebaLimite
```